# vlookup, hlookup, sumifproduct vba

Tags: vba, vlookup, product

I have to write a VBA code to get revenue for a list of customer. 
[Revenue Loop image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnd6u.png)
I am calculating monthly revenue, in which I take no. of members for a particular month and multiply by revenue per member. Revenue generated by members change over the year. Lets say, Year 1 revenue generated is $50 per member and Year 2 revenue is $40 per member.
If no. of members acquired in Jan-2010 is 10 and then total revenue for Jan 2010 would be 10 * 50= 500. In Jan-2011, no. of members acquired is 25 then revenue generated for Jan-2011 would be 10*$40 + 25*50= 1650.

I have also attached an image containing the problem.

How can I do this through VBA. My data starts from 1998 and goes till 2022. I tried putting xls formula but it gets very complicated. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnd6u.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnd6u.png)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/getting-started-with-vba-in-office

Comment: It's kind of hard to follow your example - the numbers you use in your example are not in the image.  Can you use example numbers from your image (and specify which cells you are referring to?)  Which cells are the counts of members are which are $ amounts?   From what I'm understanding so far there is no need for VBA, for simple math operations like `10*40 + 25*50`

Comment: thanks for pointing about the image. I edited it. The challenge is that revenue generated by the members keeps changing depending upon the no. of years since the member has been acquired. 
For ex. if I have to calculate revenue for Jan-2011, then I have to add members acquired in month of Jan for each year since 1998 and lookup then lookup the revenue per member table and do a sumproduct.

Comment: Count of member is in Row 9 and 10 
and revenue per member is in Row 3 and 4.
I am calculating revenue for Co. B

Comment: so Co.A and Co.B are individual; members?   Is the fee same for all members (ie., everyone's 3rd year costs the same)?  If I'm understanding properly, you should have a list of members with their "join date", and a list of "year #'s" with fee for that year.

Answer (score 0):

Not to discourage you from learning VBA, but in this case you should be able to accomplish all of this fairly easily without it.  Screenshot below.  Sample xlsx (macro-free) can be downloaded from [here](http://jmp.sh/Ybs5SVY).

<del>[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEGta.jpg)</del>
More about absolute/relative cell references [here](https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excelformulas/relative-and-absolute-cell-references/1/).

---

**EDIT**:  modified formula in screenshot below.  Are they billed during the 1st month for a partial month?

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your help. 
Sorry if my point was not clear, but if Bob's join date is Jan 2013 then it's revenue would only come in the month of Jan. So, Jan 2013 membership fee would get added in Jan 2014 then Jan 2015 and Jan 2016 onwards. It wont be added in July 2015

Comment: Also, my data is for more than 30 yrs period so the formula gets very long and complicated. For ex. in Jan 2017, I have to check Jan members from 1998 onwards for each year and multiply by revenue per member based on respective year. That's why i wanted to use VBA

Comment: Take a look at the formula in the modified screen shot above.  Thanks to the mix of relative & absolute references (with the '$' signs), this _same_ formula would work for any number of members for any number of years...  30,000+ years (**without getting any longer**), and I'm not sure that VBA would simplify anything.  (It would take more than 1 line of code like a properly structured worksheet formula offers.)  If an Excel worksheet is not sufficient I think you should consider an Access database (which is also easier to learn than VBA)

Comment: ...another thought, as for your additional tasks like `check Jan members from 1998 onwards for each year and multiply by revenue per member based on respective year`, that's where Excel's many built-on (often un-utilized) analysis functions come in, such as Pivot Tables for comparison year over year.   Have you used VBA for statistical analysis in the past?  I'd consider that a pretty advanced application, since you'd be re-writing analysis features that are already built into Excel or Access.